# How to display row number in TStringGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, tstringgrid

How do I create a column in a TStringGrid in FireMonkey that displays the row number?

If it's by using a LiveBinding, I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your forms/grids OnGetValue event handler is passed the row as one of it's parameters. Simply verify the column is the one you want and return the row number.

```
function Form1.Grid1GetValue(const Row, Col: Integer): TValue;
begin
  if Col = 0 then
    Result := TValue.From<Integer>(Row);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have Delphi XE2, so this event isn't implemented. I modified FMX.Grid's TStringGrid.GetValue to call FOnGetValue and assigned the event handler in code, and it works.

Comment: You still have the event in XE2 but it returns a Variant instead of a TValue.

Comment: It's there, but it's not implemented. It's never called, nor exposed. I implemented it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't realise you where talking about TStringGrid.